# std::sample output is ordered

Tags: c++, c++17, libstdc++

A couple of questions about the new `std::sample` from the latest libstdc++ (c++17).

Why is the output ordered according to the original input string? If you follow the example in the documentation, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample),

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "abcdefgh", out;
    std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                5, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
five random letters out of abcdefgh : adfgh
```

the output is always in alphanumerical order. If you reverse the input string the output is always in inverted alphanumerical order. It also samples without replacement, I guess this is related to my following question.

The documentation says that the function can implement *selection* and *reservoir* sampling, what is the difference between the two and how to implement them using `std::sample`?

I am also not sure of why the function takes `back_inserter_iterator` and no other `insert_iterator`.

Comment: Nothing says it cannot use other insertion iterators. `sample` takes an OutputIterator.

Comment: that's what I thought when i read the function signature, not what I found when I ran the code. If you use forward_insert_iterator or insert_iterator it won't work.

Comment: Its a back-inserter for the *target*. There is no "there" there initially in `out`, so a in-sequence insertion makes no sense; there is no sequence. The goal is to generate random picks from the *source*, and append them to the target which is initially empty.

Comment: @stefano: In what way does it "won't work?"

Comment: @WhozCraig makes sense, thank you

Comment: @stefano I think your other surprise is that the results are *stable*. (i.e. original input order is preserved) depending on the population iterator type. So you get a sample, but that sample is in whatever order the original sequence was in; i.e. not shuffled. [See better description here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample).

Comment: @WhozCraig that's interesting, so that must be related to the fact that it samples without substitution. Also not sure what the advantage of being stable is. My intuitive idea of what this algorithm should have done would be sampling with replacement and not in the same order as in the original sequence.

Comment: @stefano Presumably it follows directly from the fact that it's specified to be a linear-time algorithm and supports input iterators. It can *only* traverse the population once, strictly from begin to end, by definition.

Comment: @JohannesD thank you. One could achieve sampling M elements with replacement in random order by sorting M random samples in O(MlogM) and then traverse the string once, so it would stay O(N) if M<<N. I found this paper http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/vitter.pdf on *reservoir sampling* which specifies that the sampling should be done without replacement. I guess that settles why it behaves the way it does. IMHO `sample` is not a great name choice for this function. Something like `reservoir_sample` or `random_select` would have been more specific.

Comment: P.S. I am assuming that one cannot randomly access the input (e.g. if one wants to sample from a `set`), otherwise it wouldn't even need to be O(N)